# MVC4 Twitter Bootstrap 3 Show Modal To Edit Data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an MVC4 application. I'm currently using GridMVC to show my data, that all works fine. When a user clicks a row i want to show a bootstrap modal to edit the data. I already have a partial view with the edit fields. Whats the best way to implement a modal popup for the user to edit the data? Anyone tried this successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably put the whole bootstrap modal in your partial view with your form and html to save it.

Then on your main page just include your partial view with this 'save form' at the bottom of the document (one for every row)

```
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("_MySaveModalForm", ViewModelForRow1);
    Html.RenderPartial("_MySaveModalForm", ViewModelForRow2);
}
```

Then for your link to open the modal, just use the standard bootstrap open modal.

```
 <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal@RowID" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Edit Row</a>
```

You could put this inside your row, or use some javascript to open the modal on click of the row.

The code in the partial view will be rendered to the html page just as if they were on the same page, there really isn't anything extra you have to do.  So it's really not that different from just writing the bootstrap modal popup.

This is a rather brute force approach and might not work that well if you have lots of rows per page (as the partial view will be outputted for every row).

But it's where I would start.